# CakePHP: Database Update in a Loop - server response with Error 500

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

i want to update my database in a loop. the data are price and stock information from a xml file i load. There are about 8 thousand items i want to update. it takes quite a long time and approximately at item 3000 the server response with an error 500.

I'm wondering if there is not a better, more Cake'ish way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

For tasks like this a [shell](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html) or some kind of event dispatching system should be used. And read the data you want to change in chunks instead all at once. The way you do it will just result in filling up the memory and get an error.

And if you want to do something in the proper CakePHP stop writing bloated controllers and more critical: stop using query(). I suggest you to learn and understand MVC and some software design principles first.

Also stop using horrible variable names like "artPriceArr3" or "art". Is it an artwork? An article? An artist? Read this: [Clean Code](http://www.amazon.de/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882)

Comment: You can also use `DboSource::insertMulti()` to insert a bunch of rows in one transaction, rather than running a separate query for each insert. See [`CakeTestFixture::insert()`][http://api20.cakephp.org/view_source/cake-test-fixture#line-201] for example implementation.

Comment: @burzum thanks for reply. you are right. queries should not be in the controller. the whole is a patchwork and should be rewritten.

Comment: @user1350963 See `Model::updateAll()` (http://api20.cakephp.org/class/model#method-ModelupdateAll).

Comment: @jeremyharris thank you for the hint. insertMulti is much faster. but how can i update instead of insert a record?

Comment: ok, i've rewritten the whole funktion. i put the data-things in models and use a extra table for the updatedata from the xml. now. the whole thing takes only a few seconds ;-)

Answer (score 0):

here is my controller code – much cleaner:

```
$this->Stock->query('TRUNCATE stocks;');

$itemsFromXml   = $this->XmlPricelist->getXml();

$fields = array('id','amount','price'); 
$values     = array();

foreach($itemsFromXml as $key=>$item){
 $values[] = array($item['id'],$item['stock'],$item['price']); 
} 
$this->multiSave($this->Stock,$values,$fields);
```